# vb.net Timer Not stopping When I stop

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim aNum As Integer = 0   
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
            Label1.Text = "Timer: " & aNum
            aNum += 1

            If aNum = 20 Then
                Timer1.Stop()
                MsgBox("timer stopped")
            Else
                MsgBox("not stopped")
            End If
        End Sub
```

I'm tried to do If aNum = 20 then Do something. But the problem is when timer start then Else statement start working until timer not stopped at aNum = 20. where the problem is ?

Comment: Where is aNum = 20 condition in above code? And do you see Label1 Text updating in your UI when timer starts? OR do you see messages from one of two MsBox calls?

Comment: Can you provide the code with IF aNum = 20 THEN DoSomething END IF? Also if you want to start the timer again ... you will need to reset aNum = 0

Comment: Sorry! i changed the value and forget to undo it.

Comment: Azaz ul Haq Bro!
yes Lebel1 text updating and with msgBox popup In every-time.

Comment: Thanks for updating Imran, so you do see "timer stopped" message but after that message Timer is still running. Is that a problem?

Comment: I would suggest that you get rid of those `MsgBox` calls and use `Console.WriteLine` instead.  Depending on your `Interval` and how long you leave the message box open, it may be that the `Timer` is raising more `Tick` events while an open message box is preventing any of them being handled, so you end up with more than 20 `Tick` events queued.

Comment: Surely the real problem is located in the code that starts the timer.  It probably forgets to set aNum back to 0.

Comment: What is the timer value? As @jmcilhinney suggests it is very possible that the timer is 'ticking' whilst waiting for user input via the `MsgBox`.

Comment: @AzazulHaq yes brother ! that the problem . When Timer Stop at aNum = 20 then the IF statement is popup,

Comment: @jmcilhinney 
Those code i run on a form, so i can't use Console.WriteLine()

Comment: Of course you can use `Console.WriteLine`.  The output will be displayed in the Output window of your IDE and not interfere with your application the way I suspect that `MsgBox` currently is.  Although we pretty much all start out that way, it should be one of the first things you learn that you DO NOT use `MsgBox` or `MessageBox.Show` for debugging purposes.

Comment: I do understand !  But Nothing is printing by Console.WriteLine() [Image link](http://i63.tinypic.com/2psj68x.jpg)